# How to get Top 1 row from IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

Is there a way to get just top one row in IndexedDB? I could not find anything for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find anything so this is what I have had put in place now and it works great for my purpose. It is a hack and I'm not happy with it, but hey, for now, this will do.

I'm just storing one row as that I need in that database. And on read, I get all the rows and perform the action I need, which is only one row. When I'm inserting a new row, I'm just clearing the entire database, which is again only one row and inserting a fresh row in it.

@spiderdevil, I just saw your answer and am not sure if I will be able to try aborting the transaction, but if it works for anyone else for sure, please do share it in comments.

Answer (score 9):

Using a cursor and not calling .continue() isn't a hack at all. It's the intended way. On of the main points of cursors is exactly that they let you only fetch the information that you need.

So no need to call transaction.abort()

Answer (score 2):

Sort of a hack, but I believe that if you don't call continue() on the result object it will only process the first item.

Below is a quick example of querying with a cursor and only processing one result.

```
var db = _IndexedDatabase;
var trans = db.transaction(["Sites"], IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
var store = trans.objectStore("Sites");
var request = store.openCursor();
request.onsuccess = function (e)
{
    var result = e.target.result;
    if(!!result == false) { return; }
    // Use result.value some how

    // Comment out this line to process the first item only
    //result.continue();
};
```

Comment: I did exactly that, and that works for the moment, but when you try to close the Chrome add-on (I needed to use this in the add-on), the whole Chrome browser crashes on you.

Comment: Chrome had a few issues where using IndexedDB would crash the entire browser.  I had [submitted a defect](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108871) to the Chrome team and I believe it has now been fixed (at least in the dev version).  Try your code again in the dev or canary version of Chrome, or in Firefox as it seems to always work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Transaction.abort()

For example,if Using @Shawn's example

```
var db = _IndexedDatabase;
var trans = db.transaction(["Sites"], IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
trans.onabort = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
};
var store = trans.objectStore("Sites");
var request = store.openCursor();
request.onsuccess = function (ev)
{
    var cursor = request.result || ev.target.result;
    if(!!cursor == false)
            return;

    console.log(cursor.value);
    try{
        transaction.abort();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Get method on the index. This will return the first record for the given key, only disadvatage is you can't sort.